# Visual Basic: Variable that references another variable changes when original vairable changes

Tags: vb.net, variables, variable-assignment

Example:

```
Dim a As Integer = 1
Dim b As Integer = a
Console.WriteLine(b)
a = 0
Console.WriteLine(b)
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

For some reason changing a also changes b even though I am not actually changing b. Why does this happen, and how do I get around it.

Comment: We don't a `DataType` of `Int` in VB.

Comment: Don't assign the `b` variable = `a`

Comment: I was rushing and have corrected it.

Comment: I checked it with my computer and the result is 1 and 1.

Comment: Please put a complete example that will duplicate the problem, it works as expected on my computer.  Also what version of VS are you running?

Comment: No VB6 question here despite the tagging, just VFred.

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly produce the output you have shown.    Please provide an example that illustrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 4):

Integer is a **Value** type so when you assign 'a' to 'b' a **COPY** is made.  Further changes to one or the other will only affect that particular copy in its own variable:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a As Integer = 1
        Dim b As Integer = a

        Console.WriteLine("Initial State:")
        Console.WriteLine("a = " & a)
        Console.WriteLine("b = " & b)

        a = 0
        Console.WriteLine("After changing 'a':")
        Console.WriteLine("a = " & a)
        Console.WriteLine("b = " & b)

        Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

[image: Value Type]

If we are talking about **Reference** types, however, then it's a different story.

For example, that Integer might be encapsulated in a Class, and Classes are Reference types:

```
Module Module1

    Public Class Data
        Public I As Integer
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim a As New Data
        a.I = 1
        Dim b As Data = a

        Console.WriteLine("Initial State:")
        Console.WriteLine("a.I = " & a.I)
        Console.WriteLine("b.I = " & b.I)

        a.I = 0
        Console.WriteLine("After changing 'a.I':")
        Console.WriteLine("a.I = " & a.I)
        Console.WriteLine("b.I = " & b.I)

        Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

[image: Reference Type]

In this second example assigning 'a' to 'b' makes 'b' a **REFERENCE** to the same instance of Data() that 'a' points to.  Therefore changes to the 'I' variable from either 'a' or 'b' will be seen by both, since they both point to the same instance of Data().

See: ["Value Types and Reference Types"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t63sy5hs.aspx)