# How can I force the Integer type to be used as a Reference type without wrapping?

Tags: vb.net, object, types, pass-by-reference, reference-type

I am trying to assign a variable to another variable by reference, so that changing the value of one would change the value of both, as in this pseudo-code example:

```
Dim x as Integer = 0
Dim y as Integer = x [byRef] 
x = 1
Debug.print("x = " & x)
Debug.print("y = " & y)
'should print x = 1, y = 1
```

But of course, it prints x = 1, y = 0, because Integer is a Value type by default. So the question is, how can I force the y to be assigned to x by reference? I know an Object is a reference type, so I tried `y = Cobj(x)`, but it didn't work. I want to do this without wrapping (long to explain why, but I just can't use wrapping here). Can anyone give any suggestions, please?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm coding in VB.NET.

Comment: You should add a tag for the language or environment you're using in order to attract the right kind of people.

Comment: What do you mean with  *I can't use wrapping*? What is intended as wrapping? Is boxing/unboxing not meant as *wrapping*? What else could be *not wrapping*?. Can't you use a class with a single field/property?

Comment: To clarify: by wrapping, I meant like in the answer of this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966899/visual-basic-variable-that-references-another-variable-changes-when-original-va) (declaring Data class and then using it).

Comment: If you can't/won't use a reference type then you could work with pointers (memory locations).

Comment: How can I do that, Jimi? It seems pretty easy in C, but when I googled about doing it in .NET, it seems to be a very unconventional and poorly documented way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an integer type hold a reference in vb.  It will always hold a value, not a reference to another object.  You can, however, pass an integer variable by reference to a function or subroutine so that the function or subroutine can modify the value.  Here's an example:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x As Integer = 0

    PassByValue(x)
    Debug.Print("x = " & x) 'Prints x = 0

    PassByReference(x)
    Debug.Print("x = " & x) 'Prints x = 2
End Sub

Sub PassByValue(x As Integer)
    x = 2
End Sub

Sub PassByReference(ByRef x As Integer)
    x = 2
End Sub
```

Comment: So if write Dim y = PassByReference(x), then y will be referenced to x (meaning that changing the value of one will change the value of both), correct? Because that's what I'm aiming to achieve here. I need to have both integers referencing to the same thing inside the same function, not two different functions.

Comment: No, you can never create an integer variable that is a reference to an int.  If you need to have both referencing the same thing, use the same variable name twice.  If you can post an example of why you need two different names referencing the same thing, it would allow someone to show a way you can solve the problem, but there isn't a way to make two variables of integer type that refer to the exact same object and have both variables change together (you could do it with custom classes, but not with integer types).

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear, but I wasn't trying to suggest creating two functions, just demonstrating the difference between how VB handles a value passed to a function ByVal vs ByRef.  Typically, the reason for using ByRef is to pass a variable of value type into a function and be able to modify the variable directly within a function.

Comment: Here is a more specific example of what I'm trying to achieve: [link](https://pastebin.com/pALFNier). As you can see, I want to put a bunch of variables from various places into one container (list, array, etc.), and then modify their values in various cycles. I want to have to declare that list only once at the top of my class. Problem is, these variables get added to the list by value, not by reference, so these subs you see in my don't work. This is why I'm trying to find a way to assign these variables by reference. How can I make this work?